# How to access function or method from another module in android studio?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using Embeddinator-4000 and Xamarin to code in Visual C# and pass to Android Studio. I want to make a simple program. 
https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000
I followed the tutorial here to import aar file into android studio.

In Visual Studio Xamarin:
I had implement the codes of

```
namespace CalculatorLibrary
{
[Activity(Label = "CalculatorActivity")]
public class CalculatorActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
    }       
    public double Add(double num1, double num2)
    {
        double sum;
        sum = num1 + num2;
        return sum;
    }
}
}
```

I had an output of aar file then I import into my android studio. I want to call my Add function in android studio.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import calculatorlibrary.*;
 import md54223a39312377e7a37c3fe640756f5f0.CalculatorActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button addButton;
EditText num1text, num2text;
TextView result;
String num1string, num2string;
double num1, num2, ans;
CalculatorActivity cal = new CalculatorActivity();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addButton = findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    num1text = findViewById(R.id.num1editText);
    num2text = findViewById(R.id.num2editText);
    result = findViewById(R.id.resulttextView);

}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalculatorActivity.class);
    //startActivity(intent);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            num1string = num1text.getText().toString();
            num2string = num2text.getText().toString();
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(num1string);
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(num2string);

            cal.Add(num1,num2); //I want to call this, but it can't find the Add() function.
            //ans = Add(num1, num2);
            //result.setText(Double.toString(ans));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Import the statement

```
import android.*yourmodule*;
```

Second, make an object of methodA.java as follows:

```
yourmodule methodA = new yourmodule();
```

Last, you call the method's function.

```
methodA.Calculate()
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly you build library and want to use it?
If so then follow this:

- open android studio
- change project view to 'project'
- in the root create new folder with library name
- put there the `aar` file
- go to `settings.gradle` add in the line `include ':app', ':your-lib-name'`
- change project view to android and open the build.gradle (Module: app)
- in dependencies add `implementation project(':your-lib-name')`
- sync the project and build
- now you should be able to use you functions